# How to read data from tcp socket and update values continuously in webpage using flask

Tags: python, html, sockets, flask, jinja2

Iam trying to make a python application, which will receive real time data from tcp socket decode it and update the values in webpage continuously using flask. HTML page would be given with parameters given using jinja template tags to update values in specified format

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template
import threading
import socket
import json
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

data = {}

@app.route('/sensor_data')
def index():
    global data
    print(data)
    return render_template('sensor_data.html', data=data)
    # return jsonify(data)


def update_data(data):
    global sock
    while True:
        # read data from the TCP socket
        sock.send('A\n'.encode())
        data_str = sock.recv(1024).decode()
        data_str = {'Temperature': data_str[33:38], 'Humidity': data_str[52:57]}
        data_str = json.dumps(data_str)
        # decode JSON data
        new_data = json.loads(data_str)
        # update the data on the webpage
        data.update(new_data)
        print(data)
        # wait for 1 second
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # establish TCP socket connection
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect(('192.168.56.1', 35000))
    # start updating data
    update_data_thread = threading.Thread(target=update_data, args=(data,))
    update_data_thread.start()
    # start the Flask server
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SocketIO Data</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>SocketIO Data</h1>
    <p>Temperature: {{ data.Temperature }} *C</p>
    <p>Humidity: {{ data.Humidity }} %H</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The frontend need to have websocket, or regularly poll from the server in order to update the value, as opening the webpage will fetch only once

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this using flask-socketio, which uses a websocket as Wakeme suggested.

I did not see a specific question in your post, so maybe a tutorial like this one might help?
https://davidmatablog.wordpress.com/2019/11/14/websockets-angular-and-python-flask/comment-page-1/

Comment: I think when using websockets query will be sent to get sensor data only when webpage is opened. But in my case the command should be sent irrespective of webpage opened or closed. So i used tcp socket. When iam running my code, iam getting {} as response in webpage